# Concurrent Modification Exceptions with iterators

Tags: java, exception, iterator

I just have a general question about a program that I am doing.

I have a linked list and one of the instance variable is a version int to make sure there are no concurrent modification exceptions.

If I add an element to the linked list then I change the version.

I also use a custom iterator that iterates through the linked list that also has it's own version. When the linkedList iterator is created, it sets the iterator's version equal to the linkedList's version.

My question is:
If I remove an element with my Iterator should I change the iterators version as well?

Basically every method in the Iterator class it first checks to make sure the versions are the same, and if it's not it throws a new concurrent modification exception.

Does it matter if the iterator changes the list?

Comment: A code example would help.

Comment: it's just an arbitrary question.

Comment: In order to provide an arbitrary answer - a code example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: If I remove an element with my Iterator should I change the iterators version as well?

Yes, usually you should also change the version of your Iterator, as long as you want to allow modifications to the list by the Iterator. Otherwise you should throw a [java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html).

Have a look at how the Iterator of java.util.LinkedList handles modifications: During the add and remove methods it first calls checkForComodification()

```
final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

and at the end it will increase expectedModCount by one:

```
public void add(E e) {
    checkForComodification();
    [...]
    expectedModCount++;
}
```